# Correct syntax for updating AWS API Gateway resource policy via CLI?

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, api, command-line-interface

I am attempting to update a resource policy on my API Gateway instance via the CLI and I can't seem to find the right syntax for the JSON. In the documentation it says to use "patch-operations", and from what I understand, it needs a string of JSON for the policy. I have tried minified JSON, escaped JSON, single quotes, no quotes, and nothing seems to work. The documentation doesn't have an example of actual JSON in the value field for patch-operations, so I feel kind of lost.

I have been trying variations of this command:

`aws apigateway update-rest-api --rest-api-id abcde123 --patch-operations op=replace,path=/policy,value='{"Version":"2012-10-17","Statement":[{"Effect":"Allow","Principal":"*","Action":"execute-api:Invoke","Resource":"arn:aws:execute-api:region:000000000000:*"},{"Effect":"Deny","Principal":"*","Action":"execute-api:Invoke","Resource":"arn:aws:execute-api:region:000000000000:*","Condition":{"StringNotEquals":{"aws:SourceVpce":["vpce-123456789","vpce-987654321"]}}}]}'`

I get an error every time saying:

`Error parsing parameter '--patch-operations': Expected: '=', received: '{' for input:`

Pertinent documentation [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/apigateway/update-resource.html).

Comment: Is this Windows or Mac or other?

Comment: I'm using a Mac.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following command has been tested against my environment - ( using bash)

```sh
aws apigateway update-rest-api --rest-api-id %REST_API_ID% --patch-operations op=replace,path=/policy,value='"{\"Version
\":\"2012-10-17\",\"Statement\":[{\"Effect\":\"Allow\",\"Principal\":\"*\",\"Action\":\"execute-api:Invoke\",\"Resource
\":\"arn:aws:execute-api:region:000000000000:*\"},{\"Effect\":\"Deny\",\"Principal\":\"*\",\"Action\":\"execute-api:Inv
oke\",\"Resource\":\"arn:aws:execute-api:region:000000000000:*\",\"Condition\":{\"StringNotEquals\":{\"aws:SourceVpce\"
:[\"vpce-123456789\",\"vpce-987654321\"]}}}]}"' --region %REGION%
```

[image]

The key is to convert the JSON object to text stringified, I have  used [this site](https://onlinetexttools.com/json-stringify-text). Basically, paste your JSON into the input text box and copy the stringified text into the AWS CLI command.

More info [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-resource-policies-create-attach.html).

Comment: Amazing. Who would have thought you would have to add single quotes AND double quotes? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Here is an answer for a situation when you have a **policy in a file**, e.g. `policy.json`:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": "*",
      "Action": "execute-api:Invoke",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:execute-api:region:000000000000:*"
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Deny",
      "Principal": "*",
      "Action": "execute-api:Invoke",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:execute-api:region:000000000000:*",
      "Condition": {
        "StringNotEquals": {
          "aws:SourceVpce": [
            "vpce-123456789",
            "vpce-987654321"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Then using [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) you can **stringify** it:

```
aws apigateway update-rest-api \
     --rest-api-id <api-id> \
     --patch-operations op=replace,path=/policy,value=$(jq tostring policy.json)
```