# how to replace existing policy with json file using AWS cli?

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, aws-cli

I'm trying to update policy in one of my API gateway using AWS cli and this is for automation purposes. When I try with the policy json with command, it's succeeded, but when I try to execute it with pointing a json file it's giving errors,

```
aws apigateway update-rest-api --rest-api-id cyasdze47d --patch-operations op=replace,path=/policy,value="file://foo.json"
```

error :

```
An error occurred (BadRequestException) when calling the UpdateRestApi operation: Invalid policy document. Please check the policy syntax and ensure that Principals are valid.
```

foo.json

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "execute-api:Invoke",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:execute-api:eu-west-1:123345455:cyxxxxxd/test1/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Can anyone help me on how to replace existing policy with json file using AWS cli ?

Thanks

Comment: take a look at my answer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60568767/correct-syntax-for-updating-aws-api-gateway-resource-policy-via-cli/60570891#60570891

Answer (score 2):

You must **strinfigy** your policy first as shown in the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-resource-policies-create-attach.html#apigateway-resource-policies-create-attach-using-cli).

```
strinfigied=$(jq tostring foo.json)

aws apigateway update-rest-api --rest-api-id cyasdze47d --patch-operations op=replace,path=/policy,value=${strinfigied}
```